# Rasterizing euclidean planes

Tags: geometry, projection, transformation

I'd like to visualize a BSP tree. To do this, I need to project an arbitrary euclidean plane onto a projection plane. I was thinking about calculating the intersections of the plane with the viewing frustum (in world space), then triangulating the resulting quadrangle and projecting the 2 triangles.

Is there a better way? For example, I thought about transforming the plane into the viewing space first, creating an `ONB` (from the transformed plane normal). Then I would simply stretch the quadrangle, until it is outside of the frustum and transform the quadrangle back into world space and send it into the rendering queue.

How should I got about shading the plane approximation (quadrangle)?

Comment: "To do this, I need to project an arbitrary euclidean plane onto a projection plane" Why?

Comment: Because a `BSP` tree is made out of euclidean planes. But other visualizations are also possible.

Comment: My point was you don't need any projection.

Comment: Yeah, it is done by `GL` or `DX`, but in principle it could also be done by hand. You can edit my question, if you like.

Comment: The problem with visuallizing BSP trees in 3D is that they are deceiving, when the tree is complex you won't be able to differentiate nodes from subnodes, I recommend building a 2D graph with list of objects that each node contains, I have done both before and the latter was much more useful.

Comment: You're right, that it can easily be done wrongly, but I am asking about visualizing euclidean planes, not BSP trees per se. The issue you mention can easily be remedied.

Comment: Actually that is the only problem we faced (that was a commercial project http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71328/how-can-i-add-and-subtract-convex-polygons/71704#71704) for visualizing bsp trees, otherwise shading the plane is trivial ( can you elaborate what is the problem with shading? )

Comment: There is no problem. I was just asking for suggestion what shading algorithm I should try out for my plane(s). As you can see, I have many ideas, on how to go about, a pity there aren't any answers.

Comment: use phong/goroud shading with double faces.